# Error while installing rocksdb

Tags: software-installation, python, python3, pip

I'm trying to install Python-RocksDB package. The setup file gets downloaded, and starts to install it. In the end I get this error message, and I find no way to resolve this.

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-_wncS2/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-_wncS2/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rocksdb/_rocksdb.o -lrocksdb -lsnappy -lbz2 -lz -llz4 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/rocksdb/_rocksdb.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llz4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Try and follow this Github issue and see if it helps: https://github.com/twmht/python-rocksdb/issues/13

Comment: `llz4` means `liblz4.so`. .... Install `  liblz4-dev`.